# How can I squash/deform a cube AND keep it positioned on the ground plane?

Tags: transforms

My goal is to:

- Flatten out a cube
- Keep the cube's base on the same position of z-axis (i.e. flat on the ground plane)
- Ideally, the volume of the cube should remain constant

Think of it like a block of clay slowly flowing out to the sides:

(High quality 2d sketch:)

[image]

So here is my scene: I have a *"cube"* (black object) and a lattice (orange object) that encapsulates the cube:

[image]

Then I:

1. Selected the lattice with <kbd>B</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> -> Lattice Deform
3. Added Shape Keys under menu *Data: Object Data*

   [image]
4. Then I tried to transform the cube with the lattice. Here is the result:

   [image]

The way the cube is deformed is perfect, **EXCEPT the base of the cube does NOT stay on the ground plane** -- it gets pushed down below it.

So, my question is: how can I deform the cube like this, yet keep the base on the ground plane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a lattice you can achieve this by only using *Shape Keys*:

- Create two *Shape Keys*
- Move the top face down
- Scale the bottom outside edges outward

[image]

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thank you very much. Looks like this should work nice.

Comment: Though I'm still curious of how to limit the deformation using a lattice.

Comment: @cegaton: Yes. I played around with object constraints for both cube and lattice with location, floor etc. but it kept going below ground when transforming. As I'm at starting stages I accepted this as answer (as it works fine for my current task). Though, if anyone know how (or if it is possible) by lattice that would be interesting as well.